# Call angularjs service from simple js code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have the following angularjs service:

```
angular.module('app.main').factory('MyService', ["$http", function ($http) {
    return new function () {

        this.GetName = function () {
            return "MyName";
        };
    };
}]);
```

How can I call `GetName` function from `MyService` from legacy js code?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use [angular.injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector).  Using your code you can do something like the following:

```
angular.module('main.app', []).factory('MyService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return new function () {

        this.GetName = function () {
            return "MyName";
        };
    };
}]);


angular.injector(['ng', 'main.app']).get("MyService").GetName();
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wGeNG/

**NOTE** - You need to add "ng" as your first module before loading your custom module since your example code depends upon $http provider which is in the ng module.

**EDIT** - Using `get()` as in OP's answer **but** note this code is fetching the service without relying upon the element being bound to the app module "main.app".

Comment: Oh yes i really need this. Thanks, thumb up for you :D

Comment: A word of warning: for me this solution did not work 100% because my service tried to fetch a template defined in an ng-template element and failed to do so (did not find it). However the solution proposed by @DorCohen works perfectly in that case, too.

Comment: "`angular.injector` creates a new injector function, it does not return the one associated with the bootstrapped app." as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840247/how-to-get-rootelement-from-root-angular-object). I.e., it will inject new `$rootScope` for your service.

Comment: How to get Myservice if myservice inturns call other service?

Comment: In my case, the factory returned a function (not a **new** function), and so it looked more like this: `angular.injector(['ng', 'main.app']).get("MyService")()`

Answer (score 21):

For me it worked with:

```
angular.element(document.body).injector().get("MyService")
```

I got 'Unknown provider' error when tried this:

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'main.app']).get("MyService")
```

and as i am using jqLite, i can't do

```
angular.element('*[ng-app]')
```

because selectors are not supported by jqLite, but i got [Dor Cohen] idea. My directive ng-app is on my body tag, then i can use:

```
angular.element(document.body).injector().get("MyService")
```

or

```
angular.element(document).find('body').injector().get("MyService")
```

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me but this one did. +1

Answer (score 16):

Using the following line helps to execute my method from the angularjs service:

```
angular.element('*[ng-app]').injector().get("MyService").GetName ();
```

Comment: This solution didnt work for me but the immediate below one did.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a utility method that I use :

```
function getService(name, element) {
    element = element || '*[ng-app]';
    return angular.element(element).injector().get(name);
}
```

`getSrv("name-of_service", document.body)`