# Getting access to angular $scope from own event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

$I have a custom javascript object, that can fire events.
I would like to access the angular $scope inside the event-handler, but I have read somewhere that using angular.element(...).scope() is not good, because it's only meant for testing.

My other idea was to register the handle on my object inside the controller, but this is not working (looks like $scope.somevalue gets set, but I don't think $scope is the same object).

I have found many answers here on Stack Overflow for similar questions, but they all seem to be using directives. All I want is to get a value from the object when it's updated, and display it.

Here are the two ways I have tried.

```
var myObj = GetMyObjInstance();

// Working, but apparently it's not good practise to call .scope() on an element.
myObj.onUpdated = function(){
    console.log("myObj updated");
    var v = myObj.getValue();
    var controllerDiv = document.getElementById("controller");
    var $scope = angular.element(controllerDiv).scope();

    $scope.apply(function(){
       $scope.someValue = v; 
    });
}

// Tried to do this, thinking i would get closure on the scope.
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('controller', function($scope){
   myObj.onUpdated = function(){
       console.log("myObj updated"); // Gets logged to console...
       var v = myObj.getValue();
       $scope.somevalue = v; // ... but somevalue does not get displayed. 
       $scope.apply(); // Error, says it's not a function, so maybe this is not the right object?.
   } 
});
```

Comment: Try `$scope.$apply()` instead of `$scope.apply()`. But nevertheless, you should try to use directives and/or components.

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.$watch()`?

Comment: please console.log(v) and check it. If it is ok just change `$scope.apply();` to `$scope.$apply();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AngularJS directives to handle events and update scope.

```
app.directive("xdEvent", function() {
    return linkFn(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.on("event", function(e) {
            scope.$eval(attrs.xdEvent, {$event: e});
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
};
```

USAGE

```
<div xd-event="fn($event)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using a Service instead of a controller is a better practice. You can call a service from outside javascript with the injector like explained in this thread :
[Call angularjs service from simple js code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319784/call-angularjs-service-from-simple-js-code)

If it is still important for you to access this variables from controller, you can use $watch to tell your controller to update itself when the service variables change.

Hope this help.

A+