# How to inject Service into jquery function

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a service UserManagementService which has two depenedencies $http and $q.

I want to inject this service inside jquery function using angular.injector.

I am able to inject other services which has no depenedencies using angular.injector.

Can some body how will i inject this service into jquery function.

Sample of service is...

```
angular.module("FND").factory("UserManagementService",['$http','$q' function($http,$q){

return {
loadUsers:function(){

})
```

I want to use this service in

```
$(function(){
//angular.injector()
});
```

Comment: What exactly are we trying to achieve here? You're mixing the two frameworks and I can see a lot of negative side-effects of doing so.

Comment: Actually i am using jquery api idleTimoutJS .there is onResume function inside it I want to make rest call inside this function.

Comment: I found the solution here.....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319784/call-angularjs-service-from-simple-js-code